# Drawing movable shapes

Tags: ios, cgcontext

I am trying to develop a drawing app on iOS, drawing features are drawing a line, straight lines and shapes (square & ellipses). I can draw them by using CGContext CGContextMoveToPoint, CGContextAddEllipseInRect and CGContextAddRect, but the main catch is I need to make these drawings movable. My approach was drawing the lines/shapes on the UIImage one by one and after each drawing the lines/shapes gets accumulated in a main UIImage to be rendered together just like this tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/18840/how-to-make-a-simple-drawing-app-with-uikit.

How can I make the lines/shapes that the user draws on the UIImage movable? I am thinking that I can make a UIImageView for each drawing and use the UIImageViews to be movable. Will this be a good approach or can anybody suggest a better approach to achieving this?

Comment: You need to store the location of each *shape* so that it can be rendered in the `drawRect:` method.  To move them then you need to detect a touch above a shape and change its position and then force the view to redraw.

Comment: I am using UIBezierPath now to draw. Will CGAffineTransform help me to move a specific path in an array of UIBezierPath?